# Is there a way to avoid accordion in angular and have the same effects with collapse?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm using uib-collapse, and it works great! I just wish that I could control that I don't have more than one open div, and it seems that accordion is the way to go.

However, I found it terribly hard to apply styles on uib-accordion.

Is there a way to apply the same effect using only uib-collapse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can, just manage the collapsed state with an array.  Keep in mind the uib-collapse attribute controls whether the element is collapsed.  So you markup would look like:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="collapseToggle(0)">Toggle collapse 0</button>
<div uib-collapse="!isCollapsed[0]">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
</div>
<br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="collapseToggle(1)">Toggle collapse 0</button>
<div uib-collapse="!isCollapsed[1]">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
</div>
<br />
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="collapseToggle(2)">Toggle collapse 0</button>
<div uib-collapse="!isCollapsed[2]">
    <div class="well well-lg">Some content</div>
</div>
```

And the controller bits:

```
$scope.isCollapsed = [];

$scope.collapseToggle = function(id) {
  // if toggeling the same collapse
  // just close it.
  if ($scope.isCollapsed[id]) {
    $scope.isCollapsed.length = 0;
    return;
  }
  $scope.isCollapsed.length = 0;
  $scope.isCollapsed[id] = true;
}
```

Here is a [plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/PlCIeSIg85iF1drS6R21?p=preview) demonstrating this approach.